# ¿Como se declara y se llama una funcion con $ en Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

tengo este problema..

```
TypeError: $.slideShow is not a function
```

Estoy tratando de llamar una funcion con el signo de dolar *$*, pero este no funciona..
la declaracion es la siguiente. en mi archivo index.html..

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    $.slideShow();
</script>
```

Y en mi archivo script.js
lo tengo de la siguiente manera..

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $.slideShow = function( opcciones ){
     Console.log("Slide");
    }
});
```

Pero me indica que no existe la funcion `$.slideShow`

mi directorio esta conformado con

Proyecto
 -js
   -script.js

-index.html

PD: al momento de eliminar la funcion que he creado. y solo escribir `console.log()` en el script de `document` esta si funciona, el problema me surge al llamar la funcion..
Uso la version de Jquery: `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`.
Gracias..

Comment: por que necesitas hacer$.slideshow()? por que no solo slideshow()

Comment: Le estás asignando a tu variable slideShow una función y al llamarla en tu index lo haces como si slideShow fuera una función, cuando en realidad es una variable

Answer (score 2):

Es muy probable que no estés referenciando bien tu archivo `script.js`, si el mismo tuviera el código que muestras y estuviera bien incluido, el código debería funcionar.

```js
$(function() {
  //$.slideShow("opciones"); Error

  /*Este sería el código de `script.js`*/
  $.slideShow = function(opciones) {
    console.log("Slide");
  }

  /*Aquí no da error*/
  $.slideShow("opciones");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Otra cosa

Ten en cuenta que `document.ready` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3, conviene usar `function` en su lugar.

Tenías un error de sintaxis en el <s>`Console.log`</s>

Comment: Ya corregi el problema. en si cambie lo que me comento document.ready, osea la sintaxis de la funcion principal. y uno que otro al final. marcare como correcta la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

la explicación de por qué esto falla es debido a que tienes dos scripts en tu código:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    $.slideShow();
</script>
```

El **script.js** se carga pero como tiene un `$(document).on("ready"...` **no se ejecuta** hasta que jquery y la página se ha cargado completamente.

El segundo bloque `$.slideShow();` como no tiene el `$(document).on("ready"...` **se ejecuta de forma instantanea** y por tanto esa función no existe.

La **solución es simplemente añadir en el segundo bloque** `$(document).on("ready"...` o como comenta A. Cedano mejor `$(function() { .... });`